# why sometime execute curator code "basePath = PathUtils.validatePath(path);" succeed and faild?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

my curator version:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.9.1:compile


[INFO] +- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.9.1:compile
```

package org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.locks the code is :

```
InterProcessMutex(CuratorFramework client, String path, String lockName, int maxLeases, LockInternalsDriver driver)
{
    basePath = PathUtils.validatePath(path);
    internals = new LockInternals(client, driver, path, lockName, maxLeases);
}
```

I write a task with springframework schedule, the code above execute with the error:

```
2018-01-17 14:23:00,001 ERROR[org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$L
oggingErrorHandler:95]- Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.apache.curator.utils.PathUtils.validatePath(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

but when I write a junit, the code "validatePath" will execute succed(I debug it step by step).

Why succeed and why failed? Really Confused.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have Apache Curator version conflicts. What dependency management tool are you using? Maven? Gradle? For Maven, execute `mvn dependency:tree` (I'm not sure the command for Gradle). You'll almost certainly find that the version of Apache Curator being used by Spring is different than the one you've specified. To fix, make sure to use the correct version of Curator.